# If Andy wants to die, and Spoil's decay is stronger than his regeneration, why didn't Andy use Spoil's power to die?

Tags: undead-unluck

Andy's dream is to get Fuuko in love with him, to use her unluck power, to get an unluck event so strong that eventually it would kill him. But in the series ,he meets Spoil, who is said to have a decay power stronger than his regeneration power.

If Andy wants to die, and Spoil's decay is stronger than his regeneration, why didn't Andy use Spoil's power to die?

Comment: While Andy is driven by wish to die for once and for all as the series progresses he comes to care for Fuuko. If he does not defeat or incapacitate Spoil, Fuuko would die. So he chose to confront spoil despite knowing he could get the death he always wanted.